# Simple formula to get any linearly independent vector from any non-zero lenght vector in 3D.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In 2d I can get a linearly independent vector from any non-zero length vector $(x,y)$ by using $(-y,x)$  [because: $x*-y+y*x=0$]

Is there any similar simple expression to obtain any linearly independent vector from an arbitrary non-zero vector with three components?

I've been thinking a little while but couldn't come up with one. If it can't be done, an explaination would be pretty much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It can be done, but it depends on what you mean by simple. Are piecewise functions okay? Or do you want it continuous?

Comment: I think I can find a solution using a piecewise definition, but I was wondering if it was a simple general expression like the one for 2d. I was thinking now, for the 2d case, it can be thought as embedding the xy plane in 3d, taking a normal vector to the plane, and making a 3d rotation over that vector. Does it make sense to find a plane normal to the euclidean 3d space embedded in 4d and working a rotation matrix over that plane to find a linearly independent vector in 3d?

Comment: The space normal to the $xyz$ volume would be the four-dimensional vector $\langle 0,0,0,1 \rangle$, but in 4D, you rotate around a plane, not a vector, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can compose such a formula with projection onto the plane that is orthogonal to the

original vector, to get a formula that gives a non-zero vector *orthogonal* to the original vector.

However, [nothing that does that can be continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#Application_to_computer_graphics). $\:$ Since the projection is continuous

in both arguments whenever the original vector is non-zero, it follows that there is no

*continuous* way to get a linearly independent vector from any non-zero vector in 3d.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a perpendicular vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For two vectors to be perpendicular, their dot product must be zero. For example, let's say you want all vectors perpendicular to $[2,3,4]$. Then

$$
[2,3,4]\cdot[x,y,z]=0, 
$$
so $2x+3y+4z =0$, or $z = \displaystyle -\frac{x}{2}-\frac{3y}{4}$.

So all vectors of the form $[x,y,-x/2-3y/4]$ are perpendicular to $[2,3,4]$.

Comment: I only need a linearly independent vector (because if I understand correctly, I can get a perpendicular one then with a cross product)

I understand what you say, but I'm looking for a general solution. In your example, if x or z for example are zero, the solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & \dots & x_n \end{bmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonzero vector. We are looking for a nonzero $y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & \dots & y_n \end{bmatrix}^T$ such that $x$ is orthogonal to $y$.

Observe two cases:

1. There is $i$ such that $x_i = 0$. In that case, $y = e_i$ (all zeroes, except $1$ on the $i$-th position) is **one** such vector.
2. If all $x_i$ are nonzero, then $y_1 = x_2$, $y_2 = -x_1$, $y_k = 0$ (for $k > 2$) is **one** such vector.

I doubt that you can get a formula without observing such different cases (regardless of whether you're looking for orthogonal or just linearly independent vectors, because the later ones are easily orthogonalized).